# React executa função de Callback do Socket.io mais de uma vez

Tags: node.js, react, socket.io

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que trabalha com React js no frontend e um server em Node.js no backend. Nesse server, estou utilizando Socket.io para enviar notificações ao frontend quando determinada rotina ocorrer, para que o frontend possa executar uma outra ação.
Ocorre que, percebo que toda vez que emito um evento para o front, através da função *emit* do socket.io, o frontend executa duas vezes a função da callback, como se estivessem sendo emitidos dois eventos.
Estou procurando o erro, mas até o momento não encontrei.

Segue código do emissor do evento (Socket.io):

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer(app).listen(4555, "127.0.0.1");

const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

export default function notifyMiddleware(req, res, next) {
const { type, provider_id } = req.body;
const notification = {
    type,
    provider_id,
    date: new Date(),
};

if (notification !== null) {
    io.emit("notificacao", notification);
    res.status(200).json(notification);
    next();
} else {
    next();
}
}
```

função do Frontend(React) que trata os eventos:

```
  // Socket
  import socket from '../../services/socket';


  socket.on('notificacao', () => {
    console.log('notificacao');
  });
```

Socket.js:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:4555', {
 transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'],
});

export default socket;
```

Para testar eu disparo uma chamada através do **Insomnia** para o socket.E o retorno é positivo, o problema é que no frontend a rotina sempre executa duas vezes. Segue imagem:
https://prnt.sc/u31u6q

Answer (score 0):

Até agora não entendi o motivo da função executar mais de uma vez sempre, porém, consegui resolver colocando a função dentro do um react hook. Usando o **useEffect** sem dependência consegui fazer ela ser executada apenas uma vez, ficando assim a conexão aberta.
Segue código que resolveu meu problema:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('notificacao', () => {
    console.log('notificacao');
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: você não colocou todo o código na sua pergunta, mas, deve ser porque ao atualizar outros componentes ele é executado novamente. é um possiiblidade.